# Парсинг слабоструктурированного текста

Tags: парсер

Здравствуйте.

Есть вот такой текст1, состоящий из вопроса и ответов:

Какие три черты из пе­ре­чис­лен­ных ниже ха­рак­те­ри­зо­ва­ли прав­ле­ние царя Алек­сея Ми­хай­ло­ви­ча? Со­от­вет­ству­ю­щие цифры и за­пи­ши­те их в ответ.

```
1. цер­ков­ный рас­кол
2. на­ча­ло де­я­тель­но­сти Зем­ских со­бо­ров
3. об­мир­ще­ние куль­ту­ры
4. уга­са­ние де­я­тель­но­сти Зем­ских со­бо­ров
5. раз­дел Речи Поспо­ли­той
6. со­зда­ние кол­ле­гий
```

Также есть текст2, состоящий из вот такого (например) пояснения:

```
В прав­ле­ние царя Алек­сея Ми­хай­ло­ви­ча (1645—1676 гг.) про­изо­шел цер­ков­ный рас­кол в ре­зуль­та­те ре­форм пат­ри­ар­ха Ни­ко­на, на­чал­ся про­цесс об­мир­ще­ния куль­ту­ры и уга­са­ла де­я­тель­ность Зем­ских со­бо­ров. Пер­вый Зем­ский собор начал ра­бо­ту в 1549 году. Раз­де­лы Речи Поспо­ли­той про­шли в 1772, 1793, 1795 гг. Кол­ле­гии были со­зда­ны в 1718 году.
```

Как на основе анализа этих двух текстов, получить на выходе массив индексов с правильными ответами, т.е.:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 6
?
```

Т.е. требуется какой-нибудь готовый интеллектуальный анализатор для текста, который будет выполнять поиск подстрок в неструктурированном тексте, основываясь на отбрасывании окончаний.

Comment: [Watson](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Watson)?

(конечно, для реального применения ТС -- это шутка)

--

Кстати, правильный список ответов будет: 1, 3, 4 (5 и 6 не подходят из-за их дат, не укладывающихся в диапазон 1645—1676).

Comment: @avp, тонко. Ну, действительно, подобные проблемы способны решить разве что алгоритмы, базирующиеся на идее искусственного интеллекта. Интересно было бы узнать о таких.

Comment: Боюсь, ваше задание [AI-complete](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/AI-complete.html).

Comment: 1. [копируем каждое предложение, копируем, отбрасываем окончания][1]
2. [копируем каждый вопрос, отбрасываем окончания][1]
3. [проверяем вхождение каждого слова вопроса в каждое предложение][1]
4. ![](http://www.forum-filmowe.pl/images/smiles/kowboj.gif)

  [1]: http://s.pikabu.ru/post_img/2013/08/01/0/1375302952_1222261860.jpg

Comment: @Etki: такой подход не позволит отличить, например, «состоялся церковный раскол» от «не состоялся церковный раскол».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условия:

1. Оба текста на русском.
2. Первый текст легко парсим (т.е. состоит из пунктов 1) 2) 3) и т.д.)
3. Второй текст всегда истинный и по теме.
4. Мы согласны на правильную работу алгоритма ~60% случаях.

Алгоритм:

1. Парсим первый тест на условия (т.е. разделяем на "церковный раскол", "начало деятельности земских соборов" и т.д.)
2. Делаем следующие пункты алгоритма для каждого из условий:
3. Проходимся по второму тексту, оцениваем синонимичность каждого слова предложения со словами из нашего условия. Придётся использовать различные библиотеки и базы слов.
4. Делаем проверки на содержание "не" в нашем условии и предложении.
5. **Если** (коэффициент синонимичности > N), **то** { **если** (проверки на не совпадают (т.е. и там, и там либо не есть, либо не нету)), **то** условие верно, **иначе** условие неверно  } *(N находится методом подбора так, чтобы программа лучше работала)*.
6. Если коэффициент меньше N в каждом предложении для условия, то лучше пользователю так и написать "в тексте не сказано/программа не нашла".

Правда, этот алгоритм, например, не учитывает антонимы.

Короче, дальше начинается эвристика, а основа алгоритма примерно такая.